# White space above a vertically aligned inline-block element

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

## Code

```css
.outer {
    display: block;
    background: lightblue;
    font-size: 50px;
}

.inner {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: red;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer"><div class="inner"></div></div>
```

You can play and see the result here: https://jsfiddle.net/y1jkw3nu/5/

## Problem

I have this weird empty space above the red square.

## Question

Can someone explain to me where does this empty space come from? I understand that it's because of `font-size: 50px`, but the `.inner` div have `vertical-align: middle`. Doesn't it mean it should be positioned in the middle of the line?

Comment: vertical-align only applies to inline, inline-block and table-cell elements: you can't use it to vertically align block-level elements.

Comment: @Paulie_D The `.inner` div has `display: inline-block`

Comment: Read the description about the values. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align#values_for_inline_elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to understand what vertical-align is doing here:

> middle
>
> Align **the vertical midpoint of the box** with the **baseline of the parent** box **plus half the x-height** of the parent.

So you need to find the "baseline", the "x-height" and the midpoint of your box (this one is trivial).

To better find those values, add some text:

```css
.outer {
  display: block;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(blue 0 0) 50% calc(50% + .33em - .5ex)/100% 2px no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(#fff 0 0) 50% calc(50% + .33em)/100% 2px no-repeat
    lightblue;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.inner {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(green 0 0) 50%/100% 2px no-repeat
    red;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">ÂBp
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

In the above, note how the "blue" (baseline + half the x-height) and "green" (midpoint) line are aligned. Also note how the blue is shifted by `0.5ex` from the baseline (in white).

Even without text, the above still apply and only the font properties will affect this alignment.

> ... if each line box starts with a zero-width inline box with the element's font and line height properties. We call that imaginary box a **"strut."** (The name is inspired by TeX.).
>
> The height and depth of the font above and below the baseline are assumed to be metrics that are contained in the font. (For more details, see CSS level 3.)

That "strut" element is the one used instead of the text.

You can also reduce the size of the box and you will have space at the bottom as well:

```css
.outer {
  display: block;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(blue 0 0) 50% calc(50% + .33em - .5ex)/100% 2px no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(#fff 0 0) 50% calc(50% + .33em)/100% 2px no-repeat
    lightblue;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.inner {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 30px;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(green 0 0) 50%/100% 2px no-repeat
    red;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">ÂBp
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Thats because the 'content' inside reserves height for the text that could be there... put line-height:0 and its gone..

```css
.outer {
    display: block;
    background: lightblue;
    font-size: 50px;
line-height:0;
}

.inner {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: red;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer"><div class="inner"></div></div>
```

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Why does it reserve height for `text` if there are no text in any divs? Why is it reserve space above the `.inner` element and not under? Is there some resource where I can read more about it?

Comment: More interesting, if I set `line-height: 50px` I have this weird empty space again. Obviously the height of the line is greater than 50px, so apparently the `line-height` property doesn't define the final value for the height of a line

Comment: well.. thats how block elements work.. since you use inline(block) inside

Comment: look here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height for more details : "On block-level elements, it specifies the minimum height of line boxes within the element."